# Custom ServerVariable IIS

Tags: c#, iis, url-rewriting, web-config, request.servervariables

i am trying to create a custom servervariable with url rewrite.
Url Rewrite for IIS generates the following config entry

```
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
          <rule name="CName to URL - Rewrite" stopProcessing="true">
              <match url=".*" />
              <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(?!www)(.*)\.localfurnco\.de" />
              </conditions>
              <action type="Rewrite" url="?" appendQueryString="false" />
                <serverVariables>
                    <set name="HTTP_MANUFACTURER" value="{C:1}" />
                </serverVariables>
          </rule>   
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

But when iterating through the servervariables i can't find HTTP_MANUFACTURER.
The url rewrite seems to work but i can't get the Variable.

I am trying to call the address: *test.localfurnco.de/subdir/webservice.asmx?wsdl*.

C:1 should in this case be: "*test*".

I would be grateful for any suggestion and
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

After trying some hours i figured it out myself.
Here is the resulting rule.

```
            <rule name="CName to URL - Rewrite" stopProcessing="false">
                <match url=".*" negate="false" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="true">
                    <add input="{SERVER_NAME}" pattern="^(?!www)(.*)\.localfurnco\.de" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="?CustomValue={C:1}" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
                <serverVariables>
                    <set name="HTTP_MANUFACTURER" value="{C:1}" />
                </serverVariables>
            </rule>
```

With this rule it is possible to access the ServerVariable "HTTP_MANUFACTURER" from C#:

```
   string variable= httpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables.Get("HTTP_MANUFACTURER");
```

A Different option a friend shared with me is this:

```
   string value= HttpContext.Current.Request.Params.Get("CustomValue");
```

As you can see i rewrite the url and set a parameter which i assign the, by the pattern, filtered value.

I hope this helps somebody else.